# Solr 7.x migration from 4.1

Tags: java, solr

I am upgrading solr 4.1 to 7.5 and looks like there are huge changes. In the API in my current application we are using `getQueryParserDefaultOperator` and `getDefaultSearchFieldName` method that were present in till 6.6.0 version of solr in `class org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema`.

Can any one help me if there is a direct way to handle this.